# VB6 - ByRef argument type mismatch error - where is it?

Tags: vb6

For the 10+ years I've been using VB6, every now and then I get a "ByRef argument type mismatch" error where I simply can't find the mismatch.  After struggling for a while I've always punted by forcing the type one way or another, but this time I thought I'd ask.  I'm including all the code I think could have anything to do with this; but you can skip it now and refer to it after I demonstrate the problem:

```
Public Type PBufferType
  Location(9) As Integer ' code location
  ValueHi(9) As Integer  ' Vhi code
  ValueLo(9) As Integer  ' Vlo code
  Locked(9) As Integer   ' State of pair
  Gamma(9) As Single     ' Gamma between this segment and next
End Type

Public GammaBuffer(1) As PBufferType ' The main data type

Public SelectedBank as Integer

Function MeasureLuxAtCode(code As Integer) As Single
  Call TestPatternForm.DrawTestWindow(3, code) 
  MeasureLuxAtCode = MeasureLux(1)
End Function
```

The problem occurs below.  The "LuxMinTarget = MeasureLuxAtCode(FirstLevel)" line generates a "ByRef argument type mismatch" error, indicating that FirstLevel is not an integer.

```
Sub DetermineIdealLuxCurve()
  Dim FirstLevel, FirstDACtoMeasure As Integer
  FirstDACtoMeasure = 0
  FirstLevel = GammaBuffer(SelectedBank).Location(FirstDACtoMeasure)
  LuxMinTarget = MeasureLuxAtCode(FirstLevel)
End Sub
```

But dang it, FirstLevel *is* an integer, isn't it?  It's dim'ed an int, its value is set by a UDT that returns an int, so where did I go wrong?  If I force it to an int like this:

```
  LuxMinTarget = MeasureLuxAtCode(Int(FirstLevel))
```

the compiler/interpreter's happy.  But I'm not.

So is this a bug in the compiler or just me being dense?

Comment: Where are SelectedBank and FirstDACtoMeasure defined?

Comment: I edited the question to add those two variables.  SelectedBank = global integer and FirstDACtoMeasure = local integer.

Comment: You can only get this when calling a sub/function whose parameter(s) are passed by reference. What are the definitions of SelectedBank, FirstDACtoMeasure, DrawTestWindow() and MeasureLux()?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
Dim FirstLevel, FirstDACtoMeasure As Integer
```

This actually declares `FirstLevel` as a `Variant` and not as an `Integer` as you might expect.

This is a classic VB6 gotcha! (and you are not the first to be bitten by it).

Declaring a variable per line avoids the problem:

```
Dim FirstLevel As Integer
Dim FirstDACtoMeasure As Integer
```

Comment: Bah. I didn't notice that. Good call.

Comment: Wow, to dind out that after a decade I didn't understand the "Dim" statement...I need a drink!  Thanks!

Comment: VB6 is all gotchas :-|

Answer (score 4):

John T, You actualy can explicitly declare variables in a list.

Dim FirstLevel as Integer, FirstDACtoMeasure As Integer

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of that, and probably should have pointed it out, although I usually go with the one-per-line approach for clarity.

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. One variable declaration per line is common practice.

Answer (score 1):

As Mitch pointed out, VB6 only declares the last variable in a comma delimited list as explicitly of the type defined.  The previous entries are declared, but as variants.

To have the variables correctly declared, you need to handle them individually.

```
Dim FirstLevel As Integer
Dim FirstDACtoMeasure As Integer
```

This was also the case in previous versions of VB, IIRC, not new for for VB6.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, the **FirstLevel** variable wasn't explicity given a type, so by default it gets the Variant type.
You can force inexplicit variables to a particular type with the Def*XXX* statement at the beginning of the form/module/class.  This is a holdover from BASIC days.  For example:

```
DefInt A-Z
```

This would make the default variable type Integer for all variables (beginning with A through Z).  This default applies to the entire form/module/class, just as **Option Explicit** or **Option Base** does.  You can mix and match any VB data type and assign them to letters as you see fit.  The **DefBool**, **DefByte**, **DefLng**, **DefCur**, **DefSng**, **DefDbl**, **DefDec**, **DefDate**, **DefStr**, **DefObj**, and **DefVar** statements are available for other types.  You cannot overlap or redefine letters already defined in subsequent statements in the same form/module/class.

Comment: Upvoted because I haven't heard of those `DefXXX` statements before. That said, the last sentence doesn't appear to be accurate. It looks like I can define a _local_ variable just fine. For example, if we have `Sub Test(): Dim a As Boolean: Debug.Print a: End Sub`, then calling `Test` prints `False` while directly calling `Debug.Print a` prints `0`. So, perhaps instead of saying "in the same form/module/class", it should be "in the same scope"?

Comment: The DefXXX statements just define the _default_ type for variables instead of the Variant type.  The statements don't affect any explicit typing of variables.  It's the variable-name  letters in the DefXXX statements that cannot be overlapped.  (e.g.: a `DefLng A-Q` followed by `DefInt P-Z` is illegal as P and Q are defined twice.)  Sorry for any confusion.